# How should I model 'knowing' when an aggregate is finished being updated to trigger an event?

Tags: domain-driven-design, consistency

Aggregate `B` has calculations that need to be eventually consistent with aggregate `A`. Aggregate `A` can be mutated using eight methods and each method results in `B` needing to be updated. It seems an eventually consistent task, but the actual update time frame should be within seconds.

I don't want to rely on the application layer to 'remember' to trigger the update. ([Jimmy Bogard says this](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/30/strengthening-your-domain-the-double-dispatch-pattern/) as well.) What's the best way to model this?

1. Using a domain service with double dispatch is a pain:

   - The service will have to be a parameter on every method on `A`
   - Multiple mutation methods will usually be called in a row and I don't want to trigger an update in `B` each time a method is called.
2. Constructor injection is also a pain:

   - There are situations where `A` is not mutated, so being forced to instantiate and inject a domain service to watch for mutation that certainly won't happen feels wrong.
   - Again, multiple mutation methods will usually be called in a row and I don't want to trigger an update in `B` each time a method is called.
3. Domain events sound good but I'm not sure what that looks like. Each mutation method raises a domain event?

   - Again, multiple mutation methods will usually be called in a row and I don't want to trigger an update in `B` each time a method is called.

How do I model 'knowing' when `A` is finished being updated and knowing whether it has been updated so I can trigger `B`'s update without relying on the application layer to call methods in a particular order each time?

Or is this really a repository-level or application-level concern, even though it seems to be a domain requirement?

Comment: *"Remembering to trigger the update"* is not the phrase I would have used. It seems to imply that something is stored somewhere to be picked later by another process or thread, which is not the case. If you do 2 things in an Application Service sequentially, they are immediately executed, in-process. It's actually much less of "remembering things" than inserting a trip through a messaging system in between the 2 actions.

Comment: *"Multiple mutation methods will usually be called in a row and I don't want to trigger..."* - there might be a granularity problem here. If there's a batch of operations that leads to a single repercussion in `B`, then that batch should probably have a name in your ubiquitous language and you should have a properly-grained application service that covers it (and hypothetically, a corresponding Event published by your aggregate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number 3. is commonly used and a very straight-forward technique:

1. Raise a domain event `AChangedType1`, ..., `AChangedTypeN` on model A updates
2. Let a saga/process manager listen on `AChangedTypeX` and issue a corresponding `UpdateBTypeX` command.

It's loosely coupled (neither A nor B now about each other) and scales well (easy parallelization), and the relation between them is explicitly modeled in the long running process.

If you don't want to trigger an update to B on every change on A, then you can delay the update by some time before you send out the `UpdateBTypeX` command (as it is commonly done in network protocols, see, e.g., [TCP's delayed acks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment).

Comment: Then how do I prevent `B` from updating if the changes to `A` will be discarded instead of persisted? The part I'm not sure how to model is the 'knowing `A` is finished changing' part. It'll have to involve some cue from the repository layer, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The infrastructure that the repository uses will publish the domain events if and only if the transaction of `A` was committed successfully.

Comment: Cool, what's a good way to model that part? I'm stuck on how the infrastructure knows that these events have to wait (and others don't), and what gives the infrastructure the signal to discard or pass them on. What do people normally do?

Comment: This is highly dependent on your domain and there is no general-purpose solution.  In general, however, if `B` can only be updated when events `X`, `Y` and `Z` of `A` have been issued, then you can use a simple state machine to track the seen events.  If you merely want to avoid multiple chained updates to `B`, wait a given amount, say 1 second, and then send the command to update `B`, while ignoring all further events received between issuing the timeout and sending the command.